# Magento 2 Extension Vendor name start with digit Not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, magento2.2

Try to create **Magento 2** Module, Vendor name start with digit

Like : `app/code/3dvendor/3dmodule`  (3dvendor_3dmodule)

when run "`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`"  command we get error

Is it valid vendor and module name?
can give me any suggestion.

we get name space error while run compile command

Comment: your path should be "app/code/3dvendor/3dmodule"

Comment: please share error which you are facing while compilation.

Comment: Hi @PareshaU that is typo mistake , compile command not run

Comment: can you please paste here the error message you are getting?

Comment: Can you post your registration.php and module.xml code in your question?

Comment: we get name space error while run compile command.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the same naming convention you mentioned. Magento allowed creating the module and no errors. Please check the screenshots of setup upgrade and entry in the config.php.

[image: Setup Upgrade]

[image: entry in config.php]

Not sure if your code folder has the upper case starting letter "C" in it or you wrongly mentioned in the question. If code folder name is all lower cases "code", then it should allow creating the module as in my case.

Comment: Hi @kalyan Please run php bin/magento setup:di:compile command 
while i run compile command at that time  will get error